# Do you store data in the same database as Airflow's backend?

Tags: database, sqlite, airflow

I'm trying to find info on how to create a database, store data in the newly-created database, and fetch data from that database, all from within Airflow. All the references I can find online on how to do this though only refer to Airflow's backend database.

I'm a bit new to Airflow, and my understanding is the backend database is what Airflow uses to store and access metadata related to its own operation, as opposed to task-layer data. If I want to access a SQLite database for storing data throughout my DAG, I could just find a python library to do that for me, but I feel like that's not the conventional way of accessing databases through Airflow. **What is the conventional way of (1) creating a SQLLite database, (2) storing data in the database, and (3) fetching data from that database within airflow, for use by the tasks, as opposed to metadata used by Airflow itself?**

**Edit:**

I was asked in the comments to give a few more details about my workflow on Airflow. The goal of this DAG is to move data from a source through a data processing pipeline, and part of this process involves creating a new database and tables if one/they do not already exist, something like this:

```
fetch data >> transform data >> put data elsewhere >> send alerts based on data
```

The `fetch data` and `put data elsewhere` steps involve copying the data to a local database, and I'm trying to figure out the "right" way to do that within Airflow.

Comment: It is unclear what your workflow actually is. Is creating a database a task in your workflow? Workflows in Airflow are typically run on schedule. Will your workflow create a new database every time it runs? Please describe more precisely what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov Edited in more details. To answer directly, create the database if it doesn't already exist (on every run), and it only runs rather occasionally. Other DAGs use the data stored in the database for their own processing steps. Should I just use some random python database library or is convention to use some specific tool I don't know of within the Airflow ecosystem to copy the data, and does it go in the Airflow backend database or is that just for Airflow metadata? I feel like all the tutorials online don't do a good job at describing these conventions

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you must not use Airflow metadata database to store your data.

First of all, you need to add a connection in Airflow for the Sqlite you want to use. For creating the database you can use SqliteOperator:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_modules/airflow/operators/sqlite_operator.html

Then, you have to download the data and here you have several options:

- If you are using a version of Airflow lower than 2.0, use a PythonOperator or BashOperator
- For Airflow > 2.0, you can use TaskFlow https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#taskflow-api

Either way, you have to code how to download the data. You should use the sqlite_hook, with the method get_pandas_df (or get_records)

After that, either with taskflow or pythonoperator you upload the data to where you want to

So summarizing, you always want to search for operators that make what you want or code python scripts to run with PythonOperator, BashOperator or TaskFlow.